# What is the difference between </x:out> and </out> tags?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

In XML, what is the difference between `</x:out>` and `</out>` tags? So, for instance, if I have a `<quantity>23</x:quantity>` and a `<quantity>23</quantity>` what difference is it going to make?

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in `<x:out>` is interpreted by XML parsers as a *namespace prefix*, which is a mechanism to compose documents with two or more XML vocabularies having elements with the same local name. For example, XHTML has the `title` element, and so has SVG. Now in a document containing both XHTML and SVG markup, `title` elements need to be treated differently (for purposes of validation and with respect to allowable attributes etc.) depending on whether a given `title` element is for XHTML or SVG content, respectively. In XML, the namespace prefix (everything appearing before `:` in element or attribute names) *must* be bound with a *namespace binding* (one or more special XML attributes beginning with `xmlns` or `xmlns:`). For example, the following document uses the `xmlns:myvocabulary="http://example.com/myvocabulary"` namespace binding to assign the XML namespace prefix `myvocabulary` to the namespace name identified by the URI `http://example.com/myvocabulary`:

```
<p>
  <myvocabulary:myelement xmlns:myvocabulary="http://example.com/myvocabulary"/>
</p>
```

The fact that a namespace *name* is an URL isn't important - the XML parser just uses the URL as a string identifier for the namespace name.

**Edit**: the following isn't correct as Michael pointed out. Instead, the construct `<x:myelement>...</y:myelement>` is *always* invalid, and the namespace *prefixes*, not just the bound-to namespace names must be the same on matching start- and end-element tags.

<s>Note that XML requires wellformedness of XML content with respect to XML namespaces: a construct such as `<x:myelement>...</y:myelement>` is only valid if both the `x` and `y` namespace prefixes are bound to the same namespace name, such as in</s>

```
<x:myelement xmlns:x="http://example.com/myvocab" xmlns:y="http://example.com/myvocab">...</y:myelement>
```

In contrast, SGML (ancestor/superset of XML and HTML) doesn't *normally* (1) treat namespace prefixes or even the colon (`:`) character special and interprets the whole string `x:myelement` as element name.

See [Namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)

(1) unless using the special DSDL-9 namespace binding processing instruction defined in ISO/IEC 19757-9:2008

Comment: I'd also mention the default namespace.

Comment: *" a construct such as <x:myelement>...</y:myelement> is only valid if both the x and y namespace prefixes are bound to the same namespace name"* - no, that's incorrect information. While the choice of prefix is (largely) arbitrary, the prefix used in start and end tags must match.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you will get an error with

```
<quantity>23</x:quantity>
```

versus no error with

```
<quantity>23</quantity>
```

The prefixes that you find throughout xml documents are called namespace prefixes.
As put in the answer above, the namespacetag "x" is just a placeholder for the actual namespace, which is pretty much just a unique identifier for the scope of an element.
Namespaces are an important and uncelebrated part of working with xml, but they have a good function. Before scopes could be identified/set on a higher level with all kinds of workflow tools, the range where an element should function was defined by the given namespace of that element.

**Example:**

x = oldNamespace, xy = newNamespace.
The following code template in xslt invokes the `<x:element>` whenever it occurs in a xml document and creates a new element `<xy:element>` to which it copies the value of `<x:element>`.

```
 <xsl:template match="x:element">
   <xsl:element name="xy:element">
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The benefit of this is that the newly formed `<xy:element>` is an entirely different element when compared to `<x:element>` and when `<xy:element>` is invoked by another function of some sort, it will leave `<x:element>` alone, thereby defining the scope of the `<x:element>` and subsequently `<xy:element>`.

So the "x:" prefix does not incur a function "x" upon the element `<element>` as it might do in a different programming language (where I presume your confusion might come from), it merely places the element in a constrained environment.

Cheers!